# How can I receive an event from Azure Event Hub without using a blob storage container?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-eventhub

I am new to using Azure Event Hubs but I was wondering how I can receive events from the Event Hub without using a blob storage container. Would it be possible to set up event triggers to download the message data whenever a new message is posted (sent)? Would it make sense to use a function like the one below?

```
[FunctionName("EventHubTriggerCSharp")]
public void Run([EventHubTrigger("samples-workitems", Connection = "EventHubConnectionAppSetting")] string myEventHubMessage, ILogger log)
{
    log.LogInformation($"C# function triggered to process a message: {myEventHubMessage}");
}
```

(Taken from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-event-hubs-trigger?tabs=in-process%2Cfunctionsv2%2Cextensionv5&pivots=programming-language-csharp)

Is this the right approach for this problem? Could someone walk me through on why this would/wouldn't work and what exactly is happening here? I couldn't find a better description on the docs itself. Thanks in advance.

Comment: yes that link shows how to receive messages from an Event Hub using a Azure Function.  You could use a Logic App too which would be simpler.  It depends what you are going to do with the messages as to which might be a better choice.

Comment: Looking for an event when an event is available doesn't sound right. Are you sure Event Hubs is the right solution here?

Comment: The Functions trigger is backed by an event processor which requires storage to coordinate with other instances.  There are several Event Hubs client library types that consume messages without the need for storage - but you cannot use them with a Function trigger.   You may want to consider using Event Grid as a notification source to trigger the Function.  More information can be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/event-schema-event-hubs?tabs=event-grid-event-schema

Comment: Any particular reason you are looking for event hub without using storage?

Answer (score 0):

- Receive events from the Event Hub without using a blob storage container is not possible. To capture event messages, we will have to maintain a checkpoint store.
- Default checkpoint store we use is Azure Blob Storage. If not, we need to maintain custom checkpoint [manager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.icheckpointmanager?view=azure-dotnet).
- The event processor that supports the Functions trigger needs storage in order to communicate with other instances.

A Function trigger cannot use any of the Event Hubs client library types that can consume messages without storing them first. It can be done by using [Event Grid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/event-schema-event-hubs?tabs=event-grid-event-schema) schema.

Utilizing a block blob type storage in this method as well [Event Schema](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/event-schema#event-schema)

```
"blobType": "BlockBlob"
```

***Created a sample replica for Sending event messages through the eventhub trigger and able to trigger to portal using blob storage as shown:***

[image]
[image]

Reference:

You can also use [EventProcessorHost](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.eventprocessorhost?view=azure-dotnet).